# why if condition is not working in checkbox?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to add if condition to my demo .Mean when user select first element `name ="bbeser"`  from checkbox he is not able to select. But In my case he is able to select why 
here is my plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/fHdnWwIRgi5jFLQlCWKs?p=preview

```
$scope.itemCheckedUnCheckedhandler = function (item) {
  if (item.name=="bbeser") {
    item.checked=false
  }
  // $scope.checkedItems[index] = !$scope.checkedItems[index];
}
```

Please select first element then see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-change instead of ng-click. ng-click is too early, model would not have been changed yet. i.e

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxposiion" 
    ng-model="item.checked" 
    ng-class="{backgrounfimageset : item.checked}" 
    ng-change="itemCheckedUnCheckedhandler(item)">
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pc1Xlb?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you actually want to disable the checkbox under the given conditions. This will ensure that users cannot interact with the given checkbox.

You could do something like this in your template:

```
  <ul ng-repeat="item in a">
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" 
        ng-model="item.checked"
        ng-click="handler(item)"
        ng-disabled="item.name === 'bbeser'">
        {{item.name}}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Of course, if the disabled statement: `item.name === 'bbeser'` gets at all complicated, you should refactor it into its own method.